# Delphi Class of in C#

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, oop, factory

I know this question has been asked before, but I have yet to see a short, clear answer, so I'm hoping they won't remove this question and I will now get a clear answer:

I am currently working in C# 5.0; .NET 4.5; VS 2012. I am mostly a Delphi guy although I've done lots with C#.

In Delphi I have written hundreds of class factories that use the following sort of design (MUCH SIMPLIFIED HERE):

```
unit uFactory;

interface


type

    TClassofMyClass = class of TMyClass;
    TFactoryDict = TDictionary<TMyEnum, TClassofMyClass>;

var fDict:TFactoryDict;

implementation  

procedure initDict;
begin

    fDict:=TFactoryDict.create;
    fDict.add(myEnum1, TMyClass1);
    fDict.add(myEnum2, TMyClass2);
    fDict.add(myEnum3, TMyClass3);

end;


function Factory(const aEnum: TMyEnum): TMyClass;

var

    ClassofMyClass: TClassofMyClass;

begin

    if fDict.TryGetValue(aEnum, ClassofMyClass) then

    result := ClassofMyClass.Create(aParam);

end;

end.
```

Now: HOW do I do something like this in C#?! Seems there is **NO** 'class of ' type in C#. Am I missing something? How can I implement this type of class factory simply and elegantly in C#? This design can be implemented in Python as well - why should C# be worse?!

Comment: Are TMyClass1 and TMyClass2 subclasses of TMyClass?

Comment: @martheen yes, that's enforced by class of TMyClass

Comment: Is this still missing from C#?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Type:

```
Dictionary<ClassEnum, Type> TypeDictionary = new Dictionary<ClassEnum, Type>();

public void InitDictionary()
{
    TypeDictionary.Add(ClassEnum.FirstClass, typeof(FirstClass));
    //etc...
}

public object Factory(ClassEnum type)
{
    if (!TypeDictionary.ContainsKey(type))
        return null;

    var constructor = TypeDictionary[type].GetConstructor(....);
    return constructor.Invoke(....);
}
```

But I think you should use a generic method:

```
public T Factory<T>(): where T is MyBaseClass
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var constructor = type.GetConstructor(....);
    return constructor.Invoke(....) as T;
}
```

Here is a variety for parameterized construction:

```
public T Factory<T>(params object[] args): where T is MyBaseClass
{
    var argList = new List<object>(args);
    var type = typeof(T);
    var argtypes = argList.Select(o => o.GetType()).ToArray();
    var constructor = type.GetConstructor(argtypes);
    return constructor.Invoke(args) as T;
}
```

And of course; As with the first example, this will throw a nullpointerexception if it can't find a matching constructor...

Comment: Thanks - will check this out too. Another answer here also uses Invoke() and I've seen code on the web also using it in factory methods.

Comment: Note that this is a little less powerful than in Delphi, as you cannot enforce/rely on a subclass having a particular constructor. (And there is no generic constraint for constructors beside parameterless ones in C#.)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Delphi generics constructor constraint is also for parameterless ones. It is only when using meta classes that you can use more specific constructors as defined in the class hierarchy from TObject to the class that the meta class is defined on.

Comment: @MarjanVenema: Exactly, I was referring to C# being slightly inferior to Delphi's metaclasses.

Comment: @Stig-Rune Skansgård - I would also not need the Dictionary with enum based keys in Delphi, but the code runs on a webServer that takes XML based requests that are sent to the factory, so enums and a dictionary make it easier - can easily represent the enums in XML and send the XML enum straight to the factory. And of course sometimes I use parameterized constructors.

Comment: @Mikey aha, then I guess the first option is the way to go, just adding parameterized construction etc :)

Comment: @Stig-Rune Skansgård - Yes. Both options are good depending on the context. If I was working only in pure Delphi or C# environment I would pass only the requested type reference to the factory method - no dictionary. I had neglected to use a parameterized constructor in my example for simplicity's sake but now I added it.

Answer (score 4):

```
    class Potato
    {
    }

    class Potato1 : Potato
    {
        public Potato1(object[] param) { }
    }

    class Potato2 : Potato
    {
        public Potato2(object[] param);
    }

    enum MyEnum
    {
        E1, E2
    }

    Dictionary<MyEnum, Func<object[], Potato>> dict = new Dictionary<MyEnum, Func<object[], Potato>>(){
            {MyEnum.E1,(d)=>new Potato1(d)},
            {MyEnum.E2,(d)=>new Potato2(d)}
        };

    Potato Factory(MyEnum e, object[] param)
    {
        return dict[e](param);
    }
```

Comment: This looks great. Will have to check it out. But is '=>' C# syntax that I'm not aware of, or did you mistakenly mix in C++? I think in C# you need to wrap the constructor func in a delegate type etc.

Comment: @Mikey: That's a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

Comment: @O. R. Mapper - OK thanks. I haven't used .NET much since 2.0, VS 2005. :-) One of the reasons for my question is that I was wondering if there was something new since then to help with this. Seems there is...

Comment: Isn't it a shame that there's no array MyEnum of ... in C#

Comment: Is the Invoke needed, or can you write dict[e]()

Comment: 'Isn't it a shame that there's no array MyEnum of'. Indeed. In spite of all the cool stuff there is in C#, it's amazing that certain fundamental things that I take for granted in Object Pascal just aren't there in C#. It's that C/C++ DNA...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yea, simply dict[e]() is possible

Comment: Are those array MyEnum of exist in Oxygene? I'm curious if this is just C# design or perhaps the very .NET limitation.

Comment: @Martheen That exists in Oxygene. Meta classes too I believe. I don't think .net imposes many limitations.

Comment: Sweet. Perhaps some extension to C# one day could add that functionality

Comment: @Martheen - your solution is quite elegant but 'Func' only works for parameterless methods. I gave a simple example in my original question that does not use a parameterized constructor but usually I do need parameterized constructors - I edited the question now.

Comment: @Mikey Edited my answer. object[] could be changed to more specific example should you need it

Comment: @Martheen - OK- I will have to check this out too - looks very cool. When I looked up Func in the MSDN help it said that it worked only for methods without parameters - but now I see that it is overloaded and can take additional arguments.... A lot has changed since .NET 2.0 :)

Comment: @Mikey Yea, functional programming is basically why I can never go back to Java (though it may enter Java this year). You'll see that I don't actually answer your question directly, I just cheated by embedding a function inside a dictionary. The lambda helped to make the solution neat (they're actually possible in .NET 2.0 without lambda, but with unwieldy syntax)

Comment: @Martheen: understood it is not a direct answer. But with Func and Lambda it is elegant. I think in 2.0 you had declare a delegate type etc. But Delphi is still best for me, now that they introduced generics and anonymous methods. Pascal virtually forces you to write structured, expressive code and has some great features.No Lambdas and no Linq but you still have the most flexibility-can write very low level, or very highly abstracted, strong support for functional programming, same OOP model as C#. Biggest drawback is lack of automated garbage collection, but there are ways to do that too.

Comment: @Martheen: I gave the points to Stig-Rune Skansgård because he answered the question directly, but I ended up using your solution, Much cleaner. As David said, better to do it the C# way than impose the Delphi way on C#. And don't like reflection except when it is imperative. If I find that I'm driven to using reflection, I begin to rethink my design approach. Delphi does not support reflection, but something call RTTI which gives you limited 'reflection' -I generally avoid using that too. I am a bit of a 'purist'-rather refine the design and the code than depend on 'new fangled' notions. LOL

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you correct you want to have a reference to a static class. This is not possible in c#.

just one example of factory method implementation:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/328826/implementing-Factory-Method-in-Csharp

Comment: 'Class of' in Delphi is a metaClass - a type that can represent generically all the descendents of that base class and works with polymorphism depending on the descendant class represented. Nothing to do with static classes.

Answer (score 1):

The C# language does not support meta classes.

So you'll have to implement your factory in another way. One way is to use a switch statement on an enum:

```
switch (aEnum)
{
     case myEnum1:
         return new MyClass1();
     case myEnum2:
         return new MyClass2();
     .....
}
```

Another commonly used option is to do it with reflection which would allow you to write code closer to what you are used to doing.

And yet another option is to replace your dictionary of classes with a dictionary of delegates that return a new instance of your object. With lambda syntax that option yields very clean code.

The disadvantage of reflection is that you give up compile time type safety. So whilst the reflection based approach is probably closest to the Delphi code in the question, it's not the route that I personally would choose.

Rather than trying to shoe horn your Delphi solution into a language that does not want that approach, I suggest you look for the most idiomatic C# solution. Start with a web search for class factory.

Comment: +1 - thank you. Yes, I know about switch {case:} - Delphi also has that for enums, as you well know. 'Start with a web search for class factory' - Thank you again. Now with all due respect, please read my question again. :-)

Comment: I think I understood the question. I meant that you'll find a variety of examples of C# factories on the web. Take a look at them and pick the approach that you like the best.

Comment: +1 The OP said: "hoping... I will now get a clear answer" - that does not mean a web search. That's why the OP worded the question that way. :-)

Comment: You got the clear answer. A simple statement that there is no equivalent to class of. I've outlined three possible ways to implement a factory. I think some web search will yield more ideas. You've probably done that already and just want to know if you can do it with meta classes. Well, not quite. The closest to meta classes is to use reflection.

Comment: David you always get +1 from me for sheer dedication and encyclopedic knowledge. But...

Comment: But what? I'm just saying that there's loads of ways to do factories. It's hard to recommend one. You need to make your personal choice. And using a web search will give you some extra ideas beyond what is here. What's the harm? Although I personally can't think of any ideas beyond those I outlined, but I bet there are a few!

Comment: BUT.... : I am looking for one clear, discreet answer - the cleanest, simplest most elegant way - the closest one to the Delphi approach, which, as I know you will agree, is the BEST. I want to see them all in one place, from the experts, so I can choose the best of the best. :-)

Comment: That's where I disagree. The closest to your code is the reflection based approach. But I would opt for a dictionary of delegates. I think you need to program to the language rather than try to take one languages solution to a language where it is ill suited. I personally don't like the reflection approach. I'd avoid reflection unless there was no clean alternative. That's the point of my final paragraph.

Comment: OK - you are making an excellent point: The closest to the Delphi approach in C# will NOT be the best way to do it in C#. Point taken. Let's see what else the group comes up with... maybe you will get the prize... :-)

Comment: a dictionary of delegates might be the best way indeed... a bit more work but CLEAN AND CLEAR.

Comment: I gave the points to Stig-Rune Skansgård because he answered the question directly, but I ended up using Martheen's solution, which is indeed a dictionary of delegates - much cleaner. I agree it's better to do it the C# way than impose the Delphi way on C#. And I also don't like reflection except when it is imperative. If I find that I'm driven to using reflection, (or even RTTI) I begin to rethink my design approach. I am a bit of a 'purist': Rather refine the design and the code than rely on 'new fangled notions' :-)